# Waking up Roomba over serial

Tags: raspberry-pi, irobot-create, serial

I've been trying to mod an old Roomba 400 series (model #4220) by adding a Raspberry Pi to it.

I have the Raspberry Pi communicating over serial with the [EZSync018](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XDPMY4Z) cable. I have everything working, except that I can't seem to wake the Roomba up after it goes to sleep. I try pulsing the DD (pin 5) with `pyserial` like so:

```py
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",57600)

ser.setRTS(0)
time.sleep(0.1)
ser.setRTS(1)
time.sleep(2)
```

Even sending the *START* or *CONTROL* commands don't seem to do anything if the Roomba is asleep. If I press the power button it turns on and accepts commands normally, but I want it to be able to wake up on its own.

I have a suspicion that the cable might have a wire switched, but I wanted to post here to see if anyone else had any experience or ideas before I mutilate a perfectly good sync cable.

Any help / feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this problem? Was it a bad cable?

Comment: `I have a suspicion that the cable might have a wire switched` This can be checked pretty quickly with a multimeter by doing a continuity check across the cable.

Comment: @Chuck - there is a built-in FTDI IC which probably/might hamper testing with a multimeter, unless the shrouding is peeled back. However, if the OP *is* going to mutilate the cable anyway, then yes, it is a good quick test.

Comment: Ah fair enough! I'll admit to not having this device and didn't lookup the cable before commenting :-$